# Re-sample audio stream

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, sample-rate, recordrtc

I am using MediaStreamRecorder to record audio in client , and then I send the blob result using websocket server,

I am trying to re-sample from 44100 to 16000 in the server size , but no luck.

Any idea how to re-sample the stream ?

Thanks